# Check if is specific type instance for parameterised type

Tags: java, generics

I have a method with an template parameter:

```
public CustomClass getData(Class<? extends InterfaceA> item) {  

}
```

I have ended up with one case that this can be called with an `item` that can be an inner anonymous class that adheres to the class expected but how can I know when I got this object inside my method?
If I do `if(item.equals(ConcreteA.class))` where `ConcreteA` is the usual class that works it fails.
Also if I use class name I need to use something like:
`item.getName().equals(“com.a.b.Utils$1”);`

How can I check the instance in this case?

Comment: You're missing the `getClass()` on item. I.e. `if (item.equals.getClass()(ConcreteA.class))`. 
Still, I don't understand your problem. Why is it important to check for class-equality? What do you want to achieve with this?

Comment: @TamasRev:I need to do something specific to that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check whether the types are compatible, i.e., whether `InterfaceA` is a supertype of `item`:

```
boolean isValidType = InterfaceA.class.isAssignableFrom(item)
```

API Docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom(java.lang.Class)

Comment: If `item` is of type `Class<? extends InterfaceA>`, wouldn't `isValidType` always be true?

Comment: @AndyTuner: In theory, yes: at compile time, and assuming the code calling this method is generic. But there's no such guarantee at runtime (type erasure). Calls could also be using reflection... But there's a reason for the check needed by Jim.